# Circular dependency detected Warning from Angular local project but not on Stackblitz

Tags: angular, routes, angular-routing, angular-module

I have a very simple Angular project on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-routing-demo-5), where I have an `authorisations` module at page `/authorisations` containing three children at `/pending`, `/closed` and `/open` respectively. While everything works fine on Stackblitz, when I try to run this project locally it shows the following problem:

> WARNING in Circular dependency detected:
>   src/app/authorisations/authorisations-routing.module.ts -> src/app/authorisations/authorisations/authorisations.component.ts -> src/app/authorisations/authorisations-routing.module.ts
>
> WARNING in Circular dependency detected:
>   src/app/authorisations/authorisations/authorisations.component.ts -> src/app/authorisations/authorisations-routing.module.ts -> src/app/authorisations/authorisations/authorisations.component.ts

which makes sense, since I am using the `authorisationRoutes` variables both in the `authorisations.component.ts` and in the `authorisations-routing.module.ts`. How can I modify the structure of the code so that this circular dependency goes away?

I know I could just manually enter the path and title values in the `authorisations.component.ts`, however I would like to simply have an `*ngFor` iterating on an array. Is there a way to achieve this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Hello @Michael i can think only of one way to fix this problem:

Create `routes-constant.ts` file to hold your routes and after that import the routes inside your component and routes module.

Or after creating the routes-constant.ts file import the routes directly in your `AuthorisationsModule` where you can declare your routing module and use the routes

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forChild(authorisationsRoutes) ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class AuthorisationsRoutingModule { }


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    AuthorisationsRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [
  ]
})
export class AuthorisationsModule { }
```